# Replacing a given text in multiple files

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep

I have a C project with many headers and source files. In these files I have a comment line for version of the program. Something like:

```
/**
* all the file info and stuff....
* VER: 0.01
* rest of comments
*/

//code ....
```

I want to recursively edit the version in all sub folders of the project. Some of the files have this line and some don't. How to do so using standard gnu/linux programs? I am guessing `sed` or `grep` can help!

Comment: Can you tell what are trying to do while editing. Do you want to remove this entire piece of text or replace all or some text. Yes grep and sed are good options.

Comment: @faadi I just want to change version e.g. from 0.01 to 0.02 or 13131.2323 :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Try this

```
find . -type f -name '*.[ch]' -exec bash -c '
    grep -q "VER: [0-9]" "$1" && sed -i.bak "s/VER: [0-9].*/VER: 1.42/" "$1"
' -- {} \;
```

If you don't want to bother to produce a .bak (backup file), you can simplify a bit :

```
find . -type f -name '*.[ch]' -exec sed -i 's/VER: [0-9].*/VER: 1.42/' {} \;
```

#### Or this *xargs+grep* version

(don't work with file with space in their names)

```
grep -rl 'VER: [0-9].*' . |
    grep '.*\.[ch]$' |
    xargs sed -i 's/VER: [0-9].*/VER: 1.42/'
```

#### Or using *bash globstar* recursion

```
shopt -s globstar
sed -i 's/VER: [0-9].*/VER: 1.42/' **/*.[hc]
```

#### Or using *zsh*

```
sed -i 's/VER: [0-9].*/VER: 1.42/' **/*.[hc]
```

Comment: Why the `grep` and the `sed`?

Comment: Because even if sed don't find a match, it will produce a .bak file

Comment: Ah, that must be a bsd-ism, my GNU one doesn't do that

Comment: the character match `[ch]` should work in grep too (you used it for numbers) :) And `**/*.[ch]` should work in bash with just `globstar`, not really needing `extglob` (I find `extglob` a bit confusing, since it gives regex-style functionality with yet another different syntax. The `[ch]` works in normal globs too.)

Comment: Well spotted, post edited accordingly ^^

Answer (score 1):

I would just do separate commands for finding the files and then replacing them.

```
find . -type f \(-name "*.c" -o -name "*.h" \) | xargs grep -l "VER:  0.01" > files; 
for file in $(cat files);do sed -i "s/VER:  0.01/VER:  0.02/g" $file
done
```

Comment: What about a filename like `foo bar.c` ?

Comment: Obviously it will not work :). Whitespaces for filenames in *nix environment is not recommended. And I just assumed that this convention is being followed just like in the open source world. Good catch though.

Comment: @GillesQuenot, for that, you use `find -print0` and `xargs -0`, if your system has them (GNU utils do, as do the BSD ones on OS X, and I should really install some other *BSD to test)

Comment: @faadi, also, I think `-name "*.[ch]"` should work

Comment: (and `while read -rd '' `, instead of `for $(cat)` but then you might as well skip the file and pipe directly to `while`.)